# How to prompt the program to continue reading other csv files in csv folder even when one of the csv file is not found?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Cells(i,41) represents the csv file locations that i suppose the csv folder has it which i have stored them in my spreadsheet. However, some of my csv files are not in my csv folder but still i want the programme to continue to read what i have. Unfortunately, the programme stop with an error that says file path not found at the Set o_file = fs2.OpenTextFile line. I tried to solve the issue using error resume next and on error goto 0 but this time it cause another error at the line Do While o_file.atendofstream <> True which says object variable or with object variable not set error and i tried to use error resume next again but it still wont solve it.

```
Sub main()

call get_file_namevcap

end sub


Private Sub get_file_namevcap() 'check csv file using readdata sub


Dim i As Integer
Dim filename As String
Dim location As String
location = Me.ComboBox2
i = 2
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IndexPTN_STI").Cells(i, 41) <> ""
      filename = location & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IndexPTN_STI").Cells(i, 41) 'getting csv file name eg:"Vramp_bke_2019.09.28_09.10.51.csv"
Call readdatavcap1(filename, i)

    i = i + 1
Loop
end sub

Private Sub readdatavcap1(filename As String, i As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sl As String
Dim first As Integer
Dim second As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim fs2 As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim o_file As Scripting.TextStream
j = 2        'variable not defined at fs2


If Dir(filename) <> "" Then




Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'FileSystemObject also called as FSO, provides an easy object based model to access computer's file system.
                                                      'o_file contains filename(csv file link)
Set o_file = fs2.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, TristateFalse) '1=Open a file for reading only. You can't write to this file. TristateFalse means u get ascii file by default
                                                          '2=ForWriting, 8= Forappending
                   'o_file contains filename(text file data)
 sl = o_file.readline 'Reads an entire line (up to, but not including, the newline character) from a TextStream file and returns the resulting string.
 On Error GoTo 0

 Do While Left(sl, 1) = "#"   'Left Function is used to extract N number of characters from a string from the left side.
 sl = o_file.readline
 Loop

 Do While o_file.atendofstream <> True 'atendofstream = Read-only property that returns True if the file pointer is at the end of a TextStream file; False if it is not.
 On Error GoTo 0

    sl = o_file.readline

    first = InStr(32, sl, ",", 1) - 15 'INSTR function returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.
On Error GoTo 0

    second = InStr(first + 2, sl, ",", 1) 'syntax of InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
                                          'start sets string position for each search, string = string being search, substring= string expression searched ,
                                          'eg:InStr(1, "Tech on the Net", "t") Result: 9    'Shows that search is case-sensitive
                                          'compare= optional 1= textcompare
                                          'searching for commas in the file in this case

         If second = 0 Then
         second = Len(sl) + 1 'len=length of file string
         End If

    'Write the normal current trace
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("currentPTN_STI").Cells(j, 2 * i - 3) = Mid(sl, 15, first - 14)

         ' The MID function returns the specified number of characters in a text string, starting from a specified position (
       'ie. starting from a specified character number).
       'Use this function to extract a sub-string from any part of a text string. Syntax: MID(text_string, start_number, char_numbers).

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("currentPTN_STI").Cells(j, 2 * i - 2) = Abs(Mid(sl, first + 2, second - 2 - first)) + 0.000000000000001
    On Error GoTo 0
     End If

 j = j + 1
 Loop

 o_file.Close

end if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rely on error handling for this. It is simple to check to see if the file exists first, and then skip it if it does not exist:

```
' start your loop

If Dir(filenameIncludingPath) <> "" Then
  ' file was found, so open it and do what you want with it here

  ' dont forget to close it here when you are done

Else

    MsgBox "NOT FOUND: " & filenameIncludingPath

End If

' continue the loop
```

Keep in mind that `On Error Resume Next` should only be used in very rare cases, as this is certainly not one of them, because you are not just ignoring the one error you think might happen, you are ignoring all other possible errors as well.

Comment: I explained where in my answer. Before you try opening the file.

Comment: does your answer applies in the case where there are no missing files as well? Because i realised in the case of your answer, when there are no missing csv files, it will not read the file. But still it works perfectly fine when there are missing csv files tho

Comment: i have updated my code to show you where i have put your answer...

Comment: Is like as long as there are one csv file missing, the program will work while if all csv files are present, it will not work

Comment: sounds like you have some debugging to do then... set up some break points and check the variables as you go so you can find the problem.

Comment: so i suppose your code should work fine for both cases?

Comment: or did i made an error in putting the if Dir condition at the wrong place for my code?

Comment: all my code does it check to see if the filename exists or not. it's up to you to use it properly. if you wrote the code that you posted then this should be a simple thing for you to do.

Comment: Sorry i just want to rule out all the possibilities that could lead to the problem that im facing, thanks anyways..

Comment: I added an `Else` to my suggestion to help you with your debugging. Good luck :)

Comment: If you are getting additional unrelated errors, then those need to be addressed separately.