# VBA Object with variable or block variable not set error even when is already set

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am currently trying to set conditions such that when a CSV file is not found in the folder, it will continue to find other CSV files. However I'm facing the "object with variable or block variable not set" error at the 2nd `private sub readdatavcap2` even when I've already set `Set o_file = fs2.OpenTextFile` for both 1st and 2nd sub. I'm confused because for the 1st sub, the error does not occurs at `o_file.Close` after the `else` statement while for 2nd sub it occurs. Does anybody knows why?

```vb
Private Sub readdatavcap1(filename As String, i As Integer)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sl As String
    Dim first As Integer
    Dim second As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    Dim fs2 As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim o_file As Scripting.TextStream
    j = 2        'variable not defined at fs2

    If Dir(filename) <> "" Then
        Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'FileSystemObject also called as FSO, provides an easy object based model to access computer's file system.
                                                             'o_file contains filename(csv file link)
        Set o_file = fs2.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, TristateFalse) '1=Open a file for reading only. You can't write to this file. TristateFalse means u get ascii file by default
                                                              '2=ForWriting, 8= Forappending



         'o_file contains filename(text file data)
         sl = o_file.readline 'Reads an entire line (up to, but not including, the newline character) from a TextStream file and returns the resulting string.

         Do While Left(sl, 1) = "#"   'Left Function is used to extract N number of characters from a string from the left side.
             sl = o_file.readline
         Loop

         Do While o_file.atendofstream <> True 'atendofstream = Read-only property that returns True if the file pointer is at the end of a TextStream file; False if it is not.
             sl = o_file.readline
             first = InStr(32, sl, ",", 1) - 15 'INSTR function returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

             second = InStr(first + 2, sl, ",", 1) 'syntax of InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
                                              'start sets string position for each search, string = string being search, substring= string expression searched ,
                                              'eg:InStr(1, "Tech on the Net", "t") Result: 9    'Shows that search is case-sensitive
                                              'compare= optional 1= textcompare
                                              'searching for commas in the file in this case

             If second = 0 Then
                 second = Len(sl) + 1 'len=length of file string
             End If

             If tddb_vramp = True Then
                 ' write the Voltage Ramp to stress part
                 If i = 2 Then
                     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ramp_current").Cells(j, 1) = Mid(sl, 2, first - 2)
                 End If

                 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ramp_current").Cells(j, i) = Abs(Mid(sl, first + 2, second - 2 - first)) + 0.000000000000001
             Else
                 'Write the normal current trace
                 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("currentPTN_STI").Cells(j, 2 * i - 3) = Mid(sl, 15, first - 14)

                 ' The MID function returns the specified number of characters in a text string, starting from a specified position (
                'ie. starting from a specified character number).
                'Use this function to extract a sub-string from any part of a text string. Syntax: MID(text_string, start_number, char_numbers).

                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("currentPTN_STI").Cells(j, 2 * i - 2) = Abs(Mid(sl, first + 2, second - 2 - first)) + 0.000000000000001
            End If

            j = j + 1
        Loop

        If tddb_vramp = False Then
            myarray(i) = j - 1
        End If

        o_file.Close
    Else
        o_file.Close
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub readdatavcap2(filename As String, i As Integer)

    (rest of the code same as readdatavcap1)
    .
    .
    .


        o_file.Close
    Else
        o_file.Close <---error occurs here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: From your comment of `(rest of the code same as readdatavcap1)`, `readdatavcap1` and `readdatavcap2` are identical, so it's not clear why you have two. They both call `Close` on a null `o_file` in the `Else` branch because very explicitly that branch is only taken when `o_file` is never assigned to. If it doesn't manifest itself in the first sub, that means the `else` branch is never taken there, because `Dir(filename)`  is never `""`.

Comment: @GSerg because it is a private sub so i was thinking having the same variables in readdatavcap1 and readdatavcap2 wont affect one another? The purpose of using the o_file.Close statement after else is because if the csv file cannot be found in the folder i will close it and move on to another sub which is in this case readdatavcap 2

Comment: @GSerg this thread is somehow related to the one that i have asked previously  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258886/vba-object-with-variable-or-block-variable-not-set-error-even-when-is-already-se?noredirect=1#comment106588129_60258886  . The code that is used in that thread only works for the case where there are missing csv files but not for the case where all csv files are present which leads me to asking for help in this thread using another approach which im not sure whether it can solve this problem...

Comment: `because it is a private sub so i was thinking having the same variables in readdatavcap1 and readdatavcap2 wont affect one another?` - the variables won't affect each other, but that is *not* because they are in *private* subs. The purpose of using `o_file.Close` is to close an existing opened `o_file` object. If you never had one, like you do in the `else` branch of both subs, then you have nothing to `Close`.

Comment: @GSerg alright seems like my approach is wrong, but is there a better way such that when a CSV file is not found in the folder, it will continue to find other CSV files apart from the one that i have asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255399/how-to-prompt-the-program-to-continue-reading-other-csv-files-in-csv-folder-even

Answer (score 1):

I worked my way through your code but can't do more than confirm what GSerg already said in his first comment, i.e. you can't close a file that isn't open.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim Fn As String                            ' Filoe name
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then                      ' if OK is pressed
            SourceFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If SourceFolder <> "" Then                  ' a folder was chosen
        i = 2
        Fn = Dir(SourceFolder & "\*.csv")
        Do While Len(Fn) > 0
            readdatavcap1 Fn, i
            Fn = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub

    Private Sub readdatavcap1(filename As String, i As Integer)
        ' "filename" is a variable used by VBA
        ' your use of it may cause unexpected problems.
        ' to check, select the name and press F1.

        Dim sl As String
        Dim first As Integer
        Dim second As Integer
        Dim j As Long
        Dim fs2 As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim o_file As Scripting.TextStream
        Dim tddb_vramp As Boolean


        If Dir(filename) <> "" Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            j = 2                           'variable not defined at fs2

            ' FileSystemObject also called as FSO, provides an easy object based model
            '   to access computer's file system.
            Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


            ' o_file contains filename (csv file link)
            ' 1=Open a file for reading only. You can't write to this file.
            ' 2=ForWriting, 8= For appending
            '   TristateFalse means u get ascii file by default.
            Set o_file = fs2.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, TristateFalse)

             ' o_file contains filename(text file data)
             ' Reads an entire line (up to, but not including, the newline character)
             '  from a TextStream file and returns the resulting string.
             sl = o_file.readline
             Do While Left(sl, 1) = "#"
                ' Left Function is used to extract N number of characters from a string from the left side.
                 sl = o_file.readline
             Loop

            ' atendofstream = Read-only property that returns True if the file pointer
            '   is at the end of a TextStream file; False if it is not.
             Do While o_file.atendofstream <> True
                 sl = o_file.readline
                 ' INSTR function returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

                ' syntax of InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
                '   start sets string position for each search, string = string being search,
                '   substring= string expression searched ,
                '   eg:InStr(1, "Tech on the Net", "t") Result: 9
                '   Shows that search is case-sensitive
                '   compare= optional 1= textcompare
                '   searching for commas in the file in this case
                 first = InStr(32, sl, ",", 1) - 15     ' what if first is negative?
                 second = InStr(first + 2, sl, ",", 1)

                 If second = 0 Then
                     second = Len(sl) + 1               'len=length of file string
                 End If

                ' "ActiveWorkbook" seems not necessary unless you intend to have
                ' several workbooks, all having a sheet "Ramp_current" open at the
                ' same time, and none of them being ThisWorkbook.
                ' But if that's your intention "ActiveWorkbook" will lead to
                ' disaster sooner rather than later.
                 If tddb_vramp = True Then
                     ' write the Voltage Ramp to stress part
                     If i = 2 Then
                         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ramp_current").Cells(j, 1) = Mid(sl, 2, first - 2)
                     End If

                     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ramp_current").Cells(j, i) = Abs(Mid(sl, first + 2, second - 2 - first)) + 0.000000000000001
                 Else
                     'Write the normal current trace
                     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("currentPTN_STI").Cells(j, 2 * i - 3) = Mid(sl, 15, first - 14)

                     ' The MID function returns the specified number of characters in a text string,
                     '  starting from a specified position (ie. starting from a specified character number).
                     '  Use this function to extract a sub-string from any part of a text string.
                     '  Syntax: MID(text_string, start_number, char_numbers).

                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("currentPTN_STI").Cells(j, 2 * i - 2) = Abs(Mid(sl, first + 2, second - 2 - first)) + 0.000000000000001
                End If

                j = j + 1
            Loop

            If tddb_vramp = False Then
                myarray(i) = j - 1
            End If

            o_file.Close
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            ' if Dir(filename) = "" The o_file doesn't exist
            MsgBox filename & " wasn't found.", _
                   vbInformation, "Reading failure"
        End If
    End Sub
```

You should remove the `Else` condition from the above code. If you do that the code will do exactly nothing if the file isn't found. This fact would probably induce me to convert this procedure into a function that returns True if the file was found and False if it isn't. Perhaps that's helpful.

The point is that this procedure must be called by a `Main` proc which loops through all the files in a folder (for example) calling your proc with different file names. So, if your proc returns False the `Main` might issue a message saying that a file wasn't found. But even if you don't care for that, it's the `Main` that would select the next file after one has either been found and evaluated or not.

Comment: hi thanks for replying, the reason why i put another else condition is another attempt to make my programme to continue to search even when file path is not found. Because when i tried to remove else,  as mentioned in my earlier thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255399/how-to-prompt-the-program-to-continue-reading-other-csv-files-in-csv-folder-even , my programme works well when there are missing csv file in folder but once there are no missing csv files, it will not read the file which i am still finding a way to solve it..

Comment: The answer lies in having a `Main` procedure that calls your sub. Imagine a `Main` that calls your procedure which you have changed to a function. That function will return True or False and 'Main' will take the action you want it to take. Therefore your problem won't be solved by any change you make to your procedure but by the way you call it. It's the calling procedure that determines the next step.

Comment: i do have a Main procedure to call readdatavcap1 by calling another sub that contains readdatavcap1. The thing that im still cannot understand is despite putting  If Dir(filename) <> "" Then in readdatavcap1 to read the files, it only reads when the csv folder contains missing file but not when all files are present..

Comment: `Dir(filename)` returns "" if the file isn't found. `filename` must include the full path. Therefore, without knowing what you pass as `filename` I can't really comment on your result. However, you can examine what's happening by adding a line like `Debug.Print Dir(filename)` at that point and see what the Immediate Window displays. It's not easily understandable how "the cvs folder contains missing file". Could it be that the file being read isn't the missing one?

Comment: yeah the filename contains the full path. What i mean by "csv contains missing file" for example, when i delete one of the csv file in the folder, my programme can read all the lines. However, if i put back the csv file that is previously deleted back into the folder, no lines are being read by the programme. Actually this is based on the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255399/how-to-prompt-the-program-to-continue-reading-other-csv-files-in-csv-folder-even that i have asked just now which leads me to this thread to attempt to find a new way which obviously doesnt work..

Comment: Sorry, but I can't replicate your problem. Therefore I've added a `Main` procedure as I imagine it. Please run it. Note that the variable `i` is passed to `ReadDataVcap1` *ByRef* (by default). The value given to it in `ReadDataVcap1` will therefore be available in `Main` where it is passed back to `ReadDataVcap1`. I presume that this variable represents a row number but I have neither checked the accuracy of its functioning nor have I looked at what your `ReadDataVcap1` actually does. My job, as I see it, is to let you submit all files in a folder to `ReadDataVcap1`.